# Is it possible to add a subtype's tuple to a type's tuples array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, inheritance, types, tuples

I want to declare this constant:

```
let simultaneousGestures: [(UIGestureRecognizer.Type, UIGestureRecognizer.Type)] = 
    [(UIPanGestureRecognizer, UIPinchGestureRecognizer), 
     (UIPanGestureRecognizer, UIRotationGestureRecognizer), 
     (UIPinchGestureRecognizer, UIRotationGestureRecognizer), 
     (UIPinchGestureRecognizer, UIPanGestureRecognizer),      
     (UIRotationGestureRecognizer, UIPanGestureRecognizer), 
     (UIRotationGestureRecognizer, UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
    ]
```

But I get this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(UIPanGestureRecognizer, UIPinchGestureRecognizer).Type' to expected element type '(UIGestureRecognizer.Type, UIGestureRecognizer.Type)'
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write

```
let simultaneousGestures: [(UIGestureRecognizer.Type, UIGestureRecognizer.Type)] =
    [(UIPanGestureRecognizer.self, UIPinchGestureRecognizer.self),
     (UIPanGestureRecognizer.self, UIRotationGestureRecognizer.self),
     (UIPinchGestureRecognizer.self, UIRotationGestureRecognizer.self),
     (UIPinchGestureRecognizer.self, UIPanGestureRecognizer.self),
     (UIRotationGestureRecognizer.self, UIPanGestureRecognizer.self),
     (UIRotationGestureRecognizer.self, UIPinchGestureRecognizer.self)
]
```